# How to press <enter> automatically in Text Filter Web Part?

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

I am working in SP2013. My requirement is to filter list webpart based on value in Text Filter Web part **without** user pressing [Enter] in Text filter webpart.

I managed to set value in Text filter webpart using jquery. However, Now I want to press [Enter] key **automatically**, so that list webpart will filter data in page load based on text filter input. I tried doing the same with below JQuery code in page load but no luck.

```
var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
e.which = 13; //choose the one you want
e.keyCode = 13;
$("#inputTextBox").trigger(e);
```

Comment: After few research, I got to know that I need to trigger [Enter] at Text filter web part level and NOT on text box in Text filter webpart level. If anybody has idea let me know.

Answer (score 0):

That's what i made :

```
    var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");
    var Filter = "WebPartIDSPTextSlicerValueTextControl";
    e.which = 13; 
    e.keyCode = 13;
    $("input[id$='"+ Filter +"']").trigger(e);
```

My webpart ID like "ctl00_ctl35_g_e205adc3_6a66_4d89..." but my form is reload each time. Do you find something about this ?

Comment: Is this in attempt to answer the question?

Comment: Yes, i guess... My code work well, but it did it every time, so my form is refreshed all the time

Answer (score 0):

You have to use keypress event function to achieve this. You can get code from my below blog.

http://sanmattel.blogspot.com/2017/05/trigger-sharepoint-apply-filter-web.html

In below example ctl00_ctl42_g_33a1df20_58a6_46b7_9656_ef6f32e42d5b_SPTextSlicerValueTextControl' is the Web part id of the Text filter web part and ctl00_ctl42_g_ec3e3fa8_03e7_4e09_b1f1_9951d415b638 is the ID of the filter web part, which you can fetch from the HTML source using developer tool for IE

```
<script src="/_layouts/15/STYLES/PNG.SharePoint.Core/js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#ctl00_ctl42_g_33a1df20_58a6_46b7_9656_ef6f32e42d5b_SPTextSlicerValueTextControl').keypress(function(event){
        var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
        if(keycode == '13'){
           //Your Code that you want to execute or simply call the function RedirectUrl()
        event.preventDefault();
        ctl00_ctl42_g_ec3e3fa8_03e7_4e09_b1f1_9951d415b638_PostBack(event);
        }
    });

})
```